# Not able to build ract-native .apk

Tags: react-native

1. project directory: cd android
2. ./gradlew bundleRelease

`react-native run-android` is working fine, which means `dev apk` is working on device but, `release apk` is not build and failed with the above error.
[image]

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Did you follow the all steps before generating signed apk ? Did you create Keystore file from android studio ?